# Is there a way to find if a column name is in more then one SharePoint list?

Tags: 2007, list, dropdown

This is specific to SharePoint 2007, though I am sure it could cross over into 2010.

My situation is I am a site curator that inherited a site with 30+ lists.  Several of these lists are using a drop down list with a hard coded list of names.  Each time someone leaves the team or company I have to update all these drop down lists.  Now I am aware of 3 lists but I am sure there is more.

I do not have access to SharePoint Designer so need a solution that is non code.  But if this is something I can pass along to the SharePoint Admins to do I will be more then happy.

Once I narrow down all the lists using a particular column name I plan on changing them to a filtered lookup pulling off one list.  Until then I have to update the drop drowns manually.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 1):

There's no no-code way to do this.

Also, SPD != code access.

You could write a PowerShell script pretty quickly to do this. Or use the Client Object Model if you don't want to run code on the server.

Seeing as how you said it's SP 2007 though, the CSOM is unavailable to you. You always have SP 2007 web services though :)

Comment: Also web services.. but that is more relevant to SharePoint 2007.

Comment: Beat me to my edit. lol.

Comment: I will mention all the ideas in this thread to my SharePoint admins.  May not get response for a few days or more.

Comment: It would be quicker to just go to each list and go to list settings and manually check if they are using the column or not.

Comment: I think opening each list is going to be quicker, but as the number of lists grow the more tedious this will become.  I sent the email off to the admins we shall see what they tell me.

Comment: Turns out SharePoint admins agree that it would be quicker to just open up each list and check for the field name.